# Reading distance from ultrasonic via serial port and show it in a C# textbox

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to read the distances from ultrasonic on [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and showing it on text box on my [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application, but it  only reads one value, and I want it to keep reading and displaying the distance on my text box. Here's my code for reading the distance:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    string READ;
    READ = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    textBox1.Text = READ.ToString();
    textBox1.Refresh();
    //textBox1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a delay(thread sleep) after the refresh?

Comment: This must be code that runs on your PC, not the Arduino.  A simple explanation is that your Arduino program only sends the string once.  Boilerplate is that the PC sends a command string and the device responds with a measurement.  Use the DataReceived event to prevent your UI from hanging and displaying the "Not Responding" message in the title bar of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the serial port at constant intervals.
This will cause the OnTimerTick to run every 200 ms and will update the textBox.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Interval = 200;
        timer.Start();
        }
        string READ;
```

Then create the event of the above timer:

```
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        READ = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        textBox1.Text = READ.ToString();
    }
```

You can put also a timer.stop() and timer.start()under  buttons.

Comment: Thats not possible. What do you read on Arduino serial monitor? Please post Arduino code and the c# code to read it.